# How to cut and paste a word(s) in a text file to move it to the 3rd word in the same line on multiple lines

Tags: bash

I have a text file that I copied and pasted from a website
Unfortunately the format is a little garbled in that it places words in the wrong place to where i cant cut and paste it simply into the format that I need.  I have multiple lines of this code like about 500! Each line would take me about 1 minute -2 minutes to cut and paste the correct format.  So what I am trying to accomplish is to cut an ip address and subnet mask format like this

```
192.168.12.0/255.255.255.0
```

and translate it to this

```
192.168.12.0 /24 # <---notice with space there..
```

For example this is the line of code:

```
address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 192.168.12.0/255.255.255.0 Network IPv4
```

It should read like this:

```
address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 Network 192.168.12.0 /24 zone LAN
```

So the changes are I had to cut and paste the word "Network" to the 4th string in the code as well as change the subnetmask to space slash prefix then add the strings zone LAN to the end
Any good advice how i could accomplish a task like this?
I thought sed might work but dont know the syntax on this

I have used sed to already alter some of the code but I am stuck on the rest

```
sed -i -e 's/^.............../ipv4/' config1.txt
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question so it is more readable? Please insert output, input and code snippets inside code-blocks, so that we can see those "spaces" and lines of code exactly as they are (markdown removes newlines, etc.). See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Instead of sed, you could use vim macros to accomplish this task. Would be helpful if you provide a few lines of proper input/output.

Comment: As a side note, `...............` is better written as `.{15}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
$ cat file
address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 192.168.12.0/255.255.255.0 Network IPv4
$
$ awk '{$4= $(NF-1) FS $4; $(NF-1)="zone"; $NF="LAN"}1' file | sed -r 's^([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})/[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}^\1 /24^'
address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 Network 192.168.12.0 /24 zone LAN
```

Using awk, brought the "Network" before the 4th column, and replaced last 2 columns with "zone" and "LAN". Using sed, replaced the ip addr/subnet with 24.

Comment: Or you can do it all in `awk` using `-F'/'` and then use `split` to separate `$2` into any array. But for 500 lines, the time differences won't be critical. `5,000,000` lines -- then yes. Yep, what you have works.

Comment: Hey guys thanks very much for the answers and the help.  Sorry it was my first post.  Still trying to get used to how to format the questions so it can be easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` alone using a Field-Separator of `'/'` and then splitting the resulting `$1` and `$2` into arrays to put the output together, e.g.

```
awk -F'/' '{
    split ($1, a, " ")
    split ($2, b, " ")
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3], b[2], a[4], "/24 zone LAN"
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, simply copy/pasting the above in a terminal would result in:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{
>     split ($1, a, " ")
>     split ($2, b, " ")
>     printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3], b[2], a[4], "/24 zone LAN"
> }' file
address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 Network 192.168.12.0 /24 zone LAN
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` only solution

```
sed -E 's@(\S+ \S+ \S+) (\S+)/(\S+) (\S+) .*@\1 \4 \2 /24 zone LAN@' config1.txt
```

E.g:

```
Input : address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 192.168.12.0/255.255.255.0 Network IPv4
Match : (\S+           \S+  \S+        ) (\S+)       /(\S+)         (\S+)   .*

Output: address-object ipv4 192.168.12.0 Network 192.168.12.0 /24 zone LAN
```

This assumes each line is in the exact given format (same number of words). Therefore full words are captured by `\S+`. If not, the patterns should be further specialized as required.

`-E` is not in `POSIX` standard, i.e. might not work in some platforms.